# Symbolic manipulation within a string

Tags: python, sympy

I am generating a list of strings that are a mixture of `x`, `y` and other symbols where the `x` and `y` symbols, if they appear at all, will appear in consecutive clusters, so a string might look like this:

```
yy...x...xxyyxxx...xy...
```

With the ... representing some arbitrary string of other characters.

Using **SymPy** and declaring `x` and `y` as algebraic symbols, is there a way to convert the string above to?

```
y^2...x...x^2y^2x^3...xy...
```

That is, to get it to scan across the string and interpret any uninterrupted sequence of `n` `x`'s or `y`'s as `x^n` while leaving the rest of the string intact?

Comment: Are the other symbols each single characters?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be purely a string-manipulation problem, so `sympy` seems like overkill. Here's a solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which can be used to group adjacent elements from a sequence that are equal:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def transform_xy(string):
    def helper(s, seq):
        if s in ('x', 'y'):
            n = sum(1 for _ in seq) # can't use len(...) on an iterator
            return s if n == 1 else '{}^{}'.format(s, n)
        else:
            return ''.join(seq)
    return ''.join(helper(s, seq) for s, seq in groupby(string))
```

Example:

```py
>>> transform_xy('xxxyyxyxaaabbyyyyxxxyyaaxyyyxy')
'x^3y^2xyxaaabby^4x^3y^2aaxy^3xy'
```

Comment: Agreed. You are in Python so can use any Python tool to handle whatever form you are working with. If you want to later interpret that string as an expression with SymPy then it has the tools to do the conversion.

Comment: I'm coming round to the idea that I need to use strings as much as possible. But at some point I'm going to want it to iterate through a string with an instruction to multiply some given expression by 'x' as a symbol every time that character is encountered in the string. I'm not sure how this is done.